The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object in ember js
I updated the ember from 2.7 to 3.2 using command ember-cli-update
and after this I run the project using npm start then i'm getting error on terminal
type here
ERROR Summary:
  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack:[undefined]
  - code:  ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
  - codeFrame: [undefined]
  - errorMessage: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
  - errorType: [undefined]
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: [undefined]
    - line: [undefined]
  - message: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
  - name: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]
  - nodeAnnotation: [undefined]
  - nodeName: [undefined]
  - originalErrorMessage: [undefined]
  - stack: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
  at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
  at Object.join (path.js:1147:7)


hello! can you add more of the stack? looks like the stack is cut off right before the call to path -- this is what we use to see what is calling what to then ask further questions. thanks!!!

Also what version of node are you running?
